# Phone field is breaking my contact form

Tags: php, contacts, contact-form

I am trying to add a telephone field into a contact form but when I do, the script stops working and I don´t receive an email.

```
    <?php
// check if fields passed are empty
if(empty($_POST['name'])        ||
   empty($_POST['email'])       ||
   empty($_POST['telephone'])       ||
   empty($_POST['message']) ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
    echo "No se ha introducido toda la información.";
    return false;
   }

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email_from = $_POST['email'];
$telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

// create email body and send it    
$to = 'h.........@gmail.com'; // put your email
$email_subject = "Formulario de Contacto Con la Mochila al Hombro";
$email_body =  "Has recibido un mensaje desde el formulario de contacto de la Web. \n\n".
               "Aquí están los detalles:\n\n".
               "Nombre: $name \n\n".
               "Email: $email_from\n\n".
               "Teléfono: $telephone\n\n".
               "Mensaje: $message";    
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;            
?>
```

And this is the html I am using:

```
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Teléfono" id="telephone" required data-validation-required-message="Por favor, dinos tu teléfono para que podamos contactar contigo." />
            </div>
        </div>
```

The form works perfectly fine if I don´t put the telephone in the php script, but as soon as I add it, it stops working. I am assuming I am setting some values wrong but I really don´t know much abut PHP.

I believe now that it is a problem with the AJAX validation script.You can see the script live in here http://talleresnaj2.com/js/contacto.min.js

Comment: You forgot to give it a `name` attribute: `name="telephone"`. Now it will always be empty when you check for it.

Comment: That´s not it. I don´t have a name attribute in any of the control groups and they still work fine. I did it anyway tho, but I still can´t receive the messages on my email. @jeroen aAny other thoughts?

Comment: If you are using ajax to post the form, you should add the javascript to your question as well.

Comment: I believe that´s it. How can I add it into my script? Thanks @jeroen

Comment: What's it? What script?

Comment: You posting using ajax? edit the question and add tht js part

Comment: http://talleresnaj2.com/js/contacto.min.js @jeroen

Comment: Right, like anybody is going to try and decipher a minified javascript file...

Comment: @jeroen the JS is already desminified. Try ctrl+f5 because it might be a cache issue. I am sorry

Comment: It's desminified, The question is marked as duplicate so u better check the answr on the other question

Answer (score 1):

Your `<input />` doesn't have a `name` attribute, hence its value is never sent to the PHP script, making `empty($_POST['telephone'])` return true.

You just need to add `name="telephone"` in your `input`.

Comment: Don't think thats what makes the script break...

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Yes it does, unless the OP is using ajax.

Comment: @jeroen Think he's using ajax

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Yes, that is clear now. But it wasn't when this answer and your comment were posted.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the input name.

Try

```
<input name="telephone" type="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Teléfono" id="telephone" required data-validation-required-message="Por favor, dinos tu teléfono para que podamos contactar contigo." />
```

Comment: so you think the script broke because of that?

Comment: He is checking if the "telephone" field is empty. If it's not there, the statement will return `true`. Which in his statements suggests that it will `return false`. So it breaks.

Comment: He's using ajax

Comment: That the OP edited in. Original question didn't have that information, as my answer is based on.